Java Replace UTF-8 characters
I need to write a function to translate some "special characters" with "non-special characters". My sending system supports the whole UTF-8 charset, but my target system has only a reduced subset available.
Therefore I have a mapping table to translate this characters. This mapping table is a simple textfile, containing for example such a entry:
D̂;D

The first character is my "special character" which should be replaced by the character after the semicolon.
I read this mapping table into a HashMap:
    String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            characterMap.put(
                    line.substring(0, line.indexOf(";")),
                    line.substring(line.indexOf(";") + 1)
            );
            
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

That is working fine. Then I try to replace the characters:
        String target = "";
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : characterMap.entrySet()) {
            target = source.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

But that replacement is not working. target contains the same as source
How can I do such a function?

Did you try stepping through your code? Did you look at what the 2nd run of you loop does the the result of the 1st?

when running replace, you don't actually update source. However, you replace target. So the result of the for-loop would be that target is source with the last replacement performed on it. Instead, you might want to assign String target = source and for each iteration perform target = target.replace(...)

Replace the ; with =. You can then load the map in one go with Properties::load

I compares source and target. Of course I expected the result in target.

And I stepped through the loop. The Map is processed in the right way. Key and Value contains the right string which should be replaces in source (and stored in target)

the point was that you start with a fresh source at each iteration, discarding the replacements you performed in the previous iteration.

Out of interest, is D̂ a real, single character?

You should keep updating the result (target)
  String target = source;
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : characterMap.entrySet()) {
      target = target.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }


Thanks a lot! And sorry for beeing stupid... Of course the the loop overwrites the results in each step.
